# Is this increasing locally Lipschitz function continuously differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Given a locally Lipschitz function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g'(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $g(0) = 0$, can we conclude that it is continuously differentiable? If not, what additional condition(s) must $g$ satisfy? Physically, $g$ corresponds to the disspation term in a second order system, and I need $g'$ to be continuous to ultimately apply the Bendixson's Criterion.

I'm able to show that $g$ is also differentiable at $0$ using the properties given and the definition of the derivative, but unsure how to show $g'$ is continuous to conclude that it is $C^1$.

Comment: $g$ needs not be differentiable at $0$, see for instance the continuous extension of $g(x)=2x+x\sin\log\lvert x\rvert$. Even if you had that $g$ is differentiable at $0$, you are basically only asking that $g'$ is locally bounded and positive, and there's just not enough to work with to get $g'$ continuous (for instance, you aren't even trying to control the regularity of $g'$ away from $0$...)

Comment: The function $g(x)=2x$ for $x\ge 0$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x<0$ is not differentiable at $0.$

Comment: Thanks guys. Indeed the question statement was insufficient and after I submitted the problem set, I was told that I should've simply "assume $g$ is $C^1$ and proceed"...